# Taxonomy term not translated in edit node

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have a taxonomy called « **categories** » which have terms as listed below:
 [image]

Here the term “**visuels**” is the French version of “**visuals**” that has been translated.

Now in the edit section of an article with ‘french’ selected as the language, I am not getting the French term but instead it is listing the English version as shown below:
 [image]
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using 'Entity Translation' module and a field type 'Term reference'.

In the content type 'Article' you could try to create a new field type 'Entity Reference' with Target type 'Taxonomy term' and Entity selection
'[Your category vocabulary]'

It should works.